error connecting external database with rails
Guys im trying to connect my application to an external database to consume it.
I ad the config in database.yml at the end of file.
external_db:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: utf8
  database: db_name
  host: https://hostdb.com.br/
  username: user
  password: pass
  port: 5734

I created a model for it.
class ExternalDb < ApplicationRecord
  self.abstract_class = true
  establish_connection :external_db
end

Well.. after this I tried to make a simple consult with
x = ExternalDb.connection.execute("select * from PRODUTOS;")
And I got the follow error:
/home/rails/deploy/shared/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:87:in `rescue in new_client': could not translate host name "https://hostdb.com.br/" to address: Name or service not known (ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished)
/home/rails/deploy/shared/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/pg-1.5.4/lib/pg/connection.rb:819:in `connect_start': could not translate host name "https://hostdb.com.br/" to address: Name or service not known (PG::ConnectionBad)


Try upgrading the PG gem, and try the latest Ruby 3.0.x bug fix release which is 3.0.7. Ruby 3.0 is no longer maintained, consider upgrading to a maintained version soon.

This is a different problem. You should ask another question rather than editing this one.

https://hostdb.com.br/ is a URL specifically connecting to a web server on hostdb.com.br using the https protocol. You don't want to connect to a web server, you want to connect to a database.
hostdb.com.br is the "host", the network name of the server where the database resides.

I tried it, but got same error:
/home/rails/deploy/shared/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:87:in `rescue in new_client': could not translate host name "hostdb.com.br" to address: Name or service not known (ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished)
/home/rails/deploy/shared/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/pg-1.5.4/lib/pg/connection.rb:819:in `connect_start': could not translate host name "hostdb.com.br" to address: Name or service not known (PG::ConnectionBad)


@DiogoAmaral It seems hostdb.com.br does not exist. Check you have the correct hostname. Confirm it using psql or other database client.
